# How to loop a function through columns in a data frame and add to new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'll create some test data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
```

The function I'm trying to pass over the column variables is:

```
def standard(x):
    return (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
```

What I then want to do is run the function `standard` over each of the column variables using a for loop and add new columns to the data frame with the standardised data.

However, aside from making simple for loops I've not really done anything like this before. So any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use one line, here does applying the function on original/source dataframe, then lambda function will do the trick(*by passing an anonymous function as an argument to apply()*):

```
test_df.apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std(), axis =1)
```

> ```
> Out:
>
>            a         b            c          d
> 0     -0.381437   0.090135    -1.038400   1.329702
> 1     -0.722698   0.902806    0.817258    -0.997366
> 2     -0.521621   1.375428    -0.912505   0.058698
> 3     0.161679    0.900105    0.363529    -1.425313
> 4     -0.605061   0.527289    -1.045744   1.123515
> 5     -1.271155   0.481572    -0.253487   1.043071
> 6     -0.473747   -0.471403   -0.553750   1.498901
> 7     0.161580    1.335381    -0.935835   -0.561127
> 8     1.355149    -0.372754   0.029416    -1.011811
> 9     -1.065852   1.253947    0.276011    -0.464105
> ```
>
> ---
>
> For the : "How to loop a function through columns in a dataframe and add to new columns" you can use [pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join the source dataframe `test_df`with the new columns `standardized form columns` that will have the new name :

```
test_df.join(test_df.apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std(), axis =1), rsuffix='_std')
```

> ```
>           a          b            c          d           a_std       b_std        c_std      d_std
> 0     -0.142156   0.239129    -0.673335   1.241366    -0.381437   0.090135    -1.038400   1.329702
> 1     -0.726785   0.668620    0.595182    -0.962573   -0.722698   0.902806    0.817258    -0.997366
> 2     -1.212991   0.384315    -1.542113   -0.724365   -0.521621   1.375428    -0.912505   0.058698
> 3     0.366151    0.897416    0.511373    -0.775619   0.161679    0.900105    0.363529    -1.425313
> 4     -0.248543   0.830104    -0.668326   1.398053    -0.605061   0.527289    -1.045744   1.123515
> 5     -1.001275   0.695089    -0.016333   1.238530    -1.271155   0.481572    -0.253487   1.043071
> 6     -0.850323   -0.848182   -0.923375   0.950963    -0.473747   -0.471403   -0.553750   1.498901
> 7     0.337371    0.688291    0.009287    0.121310    0.161580    1.335381    -0.935835   -0.561127
> 8     1.976673    -0.953941   -0.271841   -2.037817   1.355149    -0.372754   0.029416    -1.011811
> 9     -1.795365   0.058748    -0.722873   -1.314415   -1.065852   1.253947    0.276011    -0.464105
> ```

[pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)

[pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: Yes, this is great! Thank you for helping! I'll be sure to remember `rsuffix` in the future as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can apply your function to every column like this:

```
std_df = test_df.apply(standard,axis = 1)]
```

You can concatinate this to your original frame like this:

```
big_df = pd.concat([ test_df, std_df], axis = 1)
```

To simplify you can run both of these together:

```
test_df = pd.concat([ test_df, test_df.apply(standard,axis = 1)], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you this adds in new columns, but is there a way to automate the process with a loop?

Comment: Why do you need the loop?  In pandas you normally don't want to loop if you can avoid it.  This would add std for all columns and a loop is unnecessary.   you want to add only for a subset of columns?

Comment: I don't need the loop it was just to try and gain some more understanding of loops in general as its something I am trying to improve, and to try and condense the code into as few lines as possible. Why do you normally want to avoid loops in pandas?

Comment: A lot of the operations in pandas are  vectorized, meaning they are run in parallell over the entire row set or column set at once.  This is normally a lot faster than looping on the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
for column in test_df:
    print(standard(test_df[column]))
```

Comment: This prints a list of the standardised variables oh do I then automate adding these to new columns?

Comment: Instead of printing you can set it where ever you need.